jOOQ: Using transaction propagations other than NESTED
As per this post, jOOQ implements the transaction propagation mode NESTED by default:
Is it possible to set the propagation mode for a specific transaction to something else?
I used Spring's TransactionTemplate and it works fine:
transactionTemplate.propagationBehavior = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW
transactionTemplate.execute {
    dslContext.truncate(OUTBOX).execute()
}

But is it also possible by purely using jOOQ API? Something like:
dslContext.transaction { cfg ->
    cfg.set(Settings()/* do something */)
}


You can implement your own TransactionProvider to override jOOQ's out of the box behaviour, or use DefaultTransactionProvider with the nested property set to false:
configuration.set(new DefaultTransactionProvider(connectionProvider, false));


Thanks a lot! Just a point for my future self: connectionProvider can be obtained using cfg.connectionProvider().
